# Why does this JSON path not work to get the first value?

Tags: json, jsonpath

The Json path in the first picture gives me a list, so then shouldn't I be able to put `"[0]"` or `"[1]"` to get the first or second value? It returns nothing instead.

How do I pick only one ID at a time from this list if not by using `"$..id[0]"` or `"$..id\[1]"`??

```json
[
  {
    "id": 2628,
    "invoices": [
      {
        "id": 898,
        "date": "2022-10-17T00:00:00",
        "lineItems": [
          {
            "id": 2408,
 
            "amount": 356
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "freeFormResponses": {},
    "accountingSoftwareCustomerKey": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2629,
    "invoices": [
      {
        "id": 899,
        "date": "2022-10-17T00:00:00",
        "lineItems": [
          {
            "id": 2409,
            "amount": 867
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "freeFormResponses": {}

  
  }
]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First select the first element from the list then it's id field.

```
$[0].id
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't try that.